# put parameters ignored rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

(solved): That's because the default parameter types for PUT is request parameters and not form parameters. Change "parameters(..)" to "formParameters(..)" and it'll work.

My code:
JUNIT test: (figure 1)

```
expect().statusCode(Status.NO_CONTENT.getStatusCode())
        .given()
        .parameters("name", name, "URL", URL)
        .cookie(cookie_name, newapi_session_id)
        .put("/IfdOrganization/"+orgGuid);
```

Server code: (figure 1)

```
@PUT @Path("/IfdOrganization/{guid}") @Produces({APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON})
public void update(@PathParam("guid") String guid, @FormParam("name") String name,@FormParam("URL") String URL,@CookieParam(session_cookie_name) String sessionId, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
}
```

The problem:
When doing a PUT in my JUnit test the parameters "name" and "URL"' value are null on the server (figure 1). If I change ".put()" to ".post()" on the JUnit test and change "@PUT" to "@POST" on the server the parameters' value is correct (figure 2). Also, when using PUT in AJAX, the parameters gets the correct value, which means that the problem not comes from the server.

I am using
eclipse kepler, windows 8 and rest-assured-1.8.0

JUNIT test: (figure 2)

```
expect().statusCode(Status.NO_CONTENT.getStatusCode())
            .given()
            .parameters("name", name, "URL", URL)
            .cookie(cookie_name, newapi_session_id)
            .post("/IfdOrganization/"+orgGuid);
```

Server code: (figure 2)

```
@POST @Path("/IfdOrganization/{guid}") @Produces({APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON})
public void update(@PathParam("guid") String guid, @FormParam("name") String name,@FormParam("URL") String URL,@CookieParam(session_cookie_name) String sessionId, @Context HttpHeaders headers) {
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the current version of RestAssured. 1.8.1 [See here](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/issues/detail?id=251)